# Dropshadow appearing around textblock itself instead of the individual text characters

Tags: wpf, xaml

In my code, I made a DataTemplate in a SurfaceListBox.  I added a drop shadow to the stack panel as well as to the textblock within the stack panel.  When I run it, the drop shadow on the textblock appears on the textblock UI element itself instead of the individual characters of text.  I am wondering why this is happening and if there is a way to fix it, so the drop shadow does appear on the text.

```
<DataTemplate>
    <StackPanel Background="WhiteSmoke" Height="190" Width="190">      
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="140"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Image VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="140" Width="140" Stretch="Fill" Source="{Binding ImagePath}" />
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding Name}" Background="#9FCC19" Width="190" Height="50" TextAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="WhiteSmoke" 
                                               FontFamily="Segoe" FontSize="20" >
                 <TextBlock.Effect>
                     <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="2" RenderingBias="Performance"/>
                 </TextBlock.Effect>
             </TextBlock>
         </Grid>
         <StackPanel.Effect>
             <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="2"/>
         </StackPanel.Effect>
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to get rid of the Background color of the TextBlock. You can put a Rectangle behind the TextBlock to achieve the same effect.

```
<DataTemplate>
    <StackPanel Background="WhiteSmoke" Height="190" Width="190">      
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="140"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Image VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="140" Width="140" Stretch="Fill" Source="{Binding ImagePath}" />
            <Rectangle Fill="#9FCC19" Grid.Row="1" Width="190" Height="50"/>
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding Name}" Width="190" Height="50" TextAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="WhiteSmoke" 
                                           FontFamily="Segoe" FontSize="20" >
                 <TextBlock.Effect>
                     <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="2" RenderingBias="Performance"/>
                 </TextBlock.Effect>
             </TextBlock>
         </Grid>
         <StackPanel.Effect>
             <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="2"/>
         </StackPanel.Effect>
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```